# Is it possible to get localized value of boolean expression in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, localization, internationalization

I use primefaces <p:datatable> component for displaying table data. Among the others, the  table contains column with boolean values expressed by   <p:selectBooleanCheckbox> component (chosen because of nice look).

However, when I try to export data  using  <p:dataExporter>, PF always renders logical values as 'true' or 'false' independently from the language. I would like to have values of those components rendered in language which I set in locale.

I have made localization of PrimeFaces calendar by adding global variable

PrimeFaces.locales['pl']= {...}

to javascript supporting PF and it works great for <p:calendar> component. Is it possible to do the same for boolean values?

Comment: I have converter which convert boolean into String in my applications. Inside converter you can use any localized strings. But I never tested it with `p:dataExporter`.

Comment: Good idea, it should work, thx.